# dotnetnuke dnnLEFTMENU doesn't show up in custom skin

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, skinning

I'm working on my own dotNetNuke skin, and I'm trying to add a dnnLEFTNAV to my skin.  However, I'm having trouble getting it to show up in the skin itself.  This is what my invocation in my .html skin looks like:

```
<object id="dnnLEFTMENU" codetype="dotnetnuke/server" codebase="LEFTMENU">
    <param name="Width" value="165px" />
    <param name="ShowOnlyCurrent" value="RootItem" />
    <param name="MaxLevel" value="2" />
    <param name="EnableEmbeddedSkins" value="false" />
    <param name="Skin" value="MinimalExtropy" />
</object>
```

When the skin is uploaded, the .html is converted to .ascx, and the incovation ends up looking like this:

```
<dnn:LEFTMENU runat="server" id="dnnLEFTMENU"  Width="165px" ShowOnlyCurrent="RootItem" MaxLevel="2" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="MinimalExtropy" />
```

There's also a header:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LEFTMENU" Src="~/Admin/Skins/LeftMenu.ascx" %>
```

However, when I look at the completed page, there is absolutely nothing where the LEFTNAV should be.

What makes this even odder is that I essentially pulled this code verbatim out of the Minimal Entropy skin, and a test page with the Minimal Entropy skin has the nav showing up as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Start out with the working skin, and test it iteratively.  Add a bit of your custom skin each time until you find the culprit.

Minimize your variables.  Debugging is all about good science.

Comment: If you could show both skins here, it would probably be easier to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy is my face red.  The page I was using the LEFTMENU on had no child menus...I was expecting it to include same-level items or at least the shell of an empty navigation but apparently not.

PBKAC